# Downloaded Raspberry Pi (32bit) showing up as (64bit) when verified with uname -m

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

I'm trying to use Raspberry Pi for a voice recognition project.

I have Raspberry Pi 4 model B.

I was having issue downloading PyTorch with the error of "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch." And I read in another place saying it might be mismatch of bit version.
I used Raspberry Pi Imager to reformat my SD card to FAT32 and then downloaded the 32 bit version of Raspberry Pi OS.

When I check using "uname -m", it shows aarch64
When I check "python -c "import struct;print(8*struct.calcsize('P'))" it shows 32

I'm not sure why it's showing aarch64 when I selected 32bit version.
I been having a lot of issue just trying to configure the system so I can download and use the OpenAI Whisper.

Comment: Add `arm_64bit=0` to /boot/config.txt and reboot. Your RPi will come up with the 32-bit kernel.

Comment: In this context it does not matter which kernel is used, the rest of the system software is still 32-bit and that is  what counts WRT linking and using other software.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate a bit on Dougie's comment:

> Add arm_64bit=0 to /boot/config.txt and reboot. Your RPi will come up with the 32-bit kernel.

What `uname -m` reports is the ISA of the kernel, not the userland (= everything else).  A 64-bit kernel can run a 32-bit userland (but not vice versa). If you want to find out what the system binaries are, use `file ...`, eg. `file $(which bash)`.  On the 32-bit OS regardless of what kernel is running, you should get:

```
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1
```

By default, if a 64-bit kernel is available on a 64-bit Pi it will be used.  Note that if the issue is software compatibility, it's the userland that counts, so you should not have to use a 32-bit kernel, and (put another way), if what you want to do still does not work, using a 32-bit kernel won't change that.